# Pluralize Flag/Unflag Link Text

Tags: flags

I want to rewrite the link text for Flags such that it includes the number of flaggings for that node, as pluralizing the output.

e.g.

- 1 Flag
- 3 Flags

I can get as far as getting the flag count and pluralizing the output using a field rewrite, but the Ajax link breaks, and the field can no longer be clicked to flag or unflag the node.

I've tried the [dlike](https://www.drupal.org/project/dlike) module, but this doesn't seem help with pluralizing the flag/unflag link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I was able to do this by changing the flag link text (in the flag configuration) to `[node:flag-machinename-vote-count]`, which gave the number of flag for that node.

Then, modifying line 57 of the flag theme file: `flag.tpl.php` to

```
<a href="<?php print $link_href; ?>" title="<?php print $link_title; ?>" class="<?php print $flag_classes ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php print format_plural($link_text, '1 Flag', '@count Flags') ; ?></a><span class="flag-throbber">&nbsp;</span>
```

Note that this is actually only changing the small php snippet that displays the link text to us the format_plural function:

this `<?php print $link_text; ?>`

to this `<?php print format_plural($link_text, '1 Flag', '@count Flags') ; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Put the code below in your views **Global:PHP** field

```
print flag_create_link('your-flag-machine-name',$row->uid);(\

$counts = flag_get_counts('user', $row->uid);

//note in my case i have to add flag links on user profiles
//change according to your need here, say('node', $node->nid).

if ($counts['your-flag-machine-name'] == 0) {
  echo 'please vote first!!';
}

if ($counts['your-flag-machine-name'] == 1) {
  echo $counts['your-flag-machine-name'] .' Like';
}
else {
  if ($counts['your-flag-machine-name'] >= 2) {
    echo $counts['your-flag-machine-name'] .' Likes';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vikram - I couldn't actually get this to work, but managed another solution.